# Get SSID of the wireless network I am connected to with C# .Net on Windows Vista

Tags: c#, wifi, windows-vista, ssid

I'd like to know if there is any .Net class that allows me to know the SSID of the wireless network I'm connected to.
So far I only found the library linked below. Is the best I can get or should I use something else?
[Managed WiFi](http://www.codeplex.com/managedwifi) (http://www.codeplex.com/managedwifi)

The method that exploits **WMI** works for Windows XP but is it not working anymore with Windows Vista.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I resolved using the library. It resulted to be quite easy to work with the classes provided:

First I had to create a WlanClient object

```
wlan = new WlanClient();
```

And then I can get the list of the SSIDs the PC is connected to with this code:

```
Collection<String> connectedSsids = new Collection<string>();

foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanInterface in wlan.Interfaces)
{
   Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = wlanInterface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid;
   connectedSsids.Add(new String(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ssid.SSID,0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength)));
}
```

Comment: This does not work. It requires including an assembly that I did not manage to find! Can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: @MrAsterisco: You need the Managed WiFi (http://www.codeplex.com/managedwifi) library mentioned above.

Comment: WlanClient not found.

Comment: The library I used to make this code work is called SimpleWifi, available here: [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleWifi) / [GitHub](https://github.com/DigiExam/simplewifi)

Answer (score 9):

We were using the managed wifi library, but it throws exceptions if the network is disconnected during a query.

Try:

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
    FileName = "netsh.exe",
    Arguments = "wlan show interfaces",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
process.Start();

var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var line = output.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains("SSID") && !l.Contains("BSSID"));
if (line == null)
{
    return string.Empty;
}
var ssid = line.Split(new[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].TrimStart();
return ssid;
```

Comment: This may not work in all Windows languages, as the output of netsh is localized.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this will do what you want:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
"SELECT * FROM MSNdis_80211_ServiceSetIdentifier");


foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("MSNdis_80211_ServiceSetIdentifier instance");
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

    if(queryObj["Ndis80211SsId"] == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Ndis80211SsId: {0}",queryObj["Ndis80211SsId"]);
    else
    {
        Byte[] arrNdis80211SsId = (Byte[])
        (queryObj["Ndis80211SsId"]);
        foreach (Byte arrValue in arrNdis80211SsId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ndis80211SsId: {0}", arrValue);
        }
    }
}
```

from http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/657473-wmi-wifi-discovery

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this method is not working with Windows Vista.
Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

there is some more information in [How do I get the available wifi APs and their signal strength in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496568/how-do-i-get-the-available-wifi-aps-and-their-signal-strength-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

(cross-posted in [How to get currently connected wifi SSID in c# using WMI or System.Net.NetworkInformation windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346232/how-to-get-currently-connected-wifi-ssid-in-c-sharp-using-wmi-or-system-net-netw))

I found a rather old library dating back to 2014:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Core version 1.1.0.2
```

Although it is not conforming to .NET Standard, this library integrates with my .NET Core 3.0 app, but obviously is not cross-platform.

Sample code:

```
var networks = NetworkListManager.GetNetworks(NetworkConnectivityLevels.Connected);            
foreach (var network in networks) { 
    sConnected = ((network.IsConnected == true) ? " (connected)" : " (disconnected)");
    Console.WriteLine("Network : " + network.Name + " - Category : " + network.Category.ToString() + sConnected);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use native WLAN API. There is a long discussion about it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/a2daf71e-b0f2-4d0d-bbf0-54518881cafd/#page:1). Apparently this is what Managed Wifi API uses, so it will be easier for you to use it if you do not have any restrictions to use LGPL code.

Comment: That is what I did. It revealed to be easy. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do exactly this, and tried using ManagedWifi, as suggested in other answers. But that led to unresolvable Exceptions as per here:
[Issues with using Managed WiFi (NativeWiFi API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371871/issues-with-using-managed-wifi-nativewifi-api/60115715#60115715)

I solved this by switching to using [SimpleWiFi](https://github.com/DigiExam/simplewifi/blob/master/SimpleWifi/Win32/WlanApi.cs#L131) entirely and ignored the ManagedWifi package.

Glancing at the source code, it looks like SW is a fixed reimplementation of some of the functionality in MW.