# How to automatically detect a connected SSID using C#

Tags: c#, wifi

I was wondering if there is any method to automatically detect whether I'm connected to a specific network's SSID when using C#.

I saw examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331570/how-to-get-ssid-and-rssi-for-win7-using-c-sharp), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428873/how-do-i-know-if-my-computers-not-connected-to-a-network) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431755/get-ssid-of-the-wireless-network-i-am-connected-to-with-c-sharp-net-on-windows) .

What I really wanted was for my application to be able to automatically detect that I'm connected or disconnected to that SSID to perform some functions for each cases.

Please and thank you for the help

Comment: what is the question? why don't you just loop polling the data?

Comment: If I were to loop poll, wouldn't it harm the processor cause I need to condition to be continuously checked.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to find some answer on better loop polling from [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9812/polling-loop-always-a-bad-decision) . Now what I wanna know is it possible to do it with a WiFi connection?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. What I wanted was an application in .net that when open will check whether I'm connected to a specific wifi network and then lock my screen, keyboard and mouse in Windows 7; but then unlock it back when I'm connected.