# How can I get the name of the current (WLAN) network in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, wifi

could someone help me by getting the name of the current connected (WLAN) network in C#?
Or, in addition how can I see if this network changed?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get SSID of the wireless network I am connected to with C# .Net on Windows Vista](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431755/get-ssid-of-the-wireless-network-i-am-connected-to-with-c-net-on-windows-vista)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get SSID of the wireless network I am connected to with C# .Net on Windows Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431755/get-ssid-of-the-wireless-network-i-am-connected-to-with-c-sharp-net-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431755/get-ssid-of-the-wireless-network-i-am-connected-to-with-c-net-on-windows-vista).