# How to get currently connected wifi SSID in c# using WMI or System.Net.NetworkInformation windows 10?

Tags: c#, wmi, ssid

**I have tried in 2 different ways**

### **First way: null exception issue**

```
try{

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSNdis_80211_ServiceSetIdentifier");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
       Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
       Console.WriteLine("MSNdis_80211_ServiceSetIdentifier instance");
       Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

       if (queryObj["Ndis80211SsId"] == null)
       {
           //Console.WriteLine("Ndis80211SsId: {0}",queryObj["Ndis80211SsId"]);
       }
       else
       {
           Byte[] arrNdis80211SsId = (Byte[])
           (queryObj["Ndis80211SsId"]);
           foreach (Byte arrValue in arrNdis80211SsId)
           {
              //Console.WriteLine("Ndis80211SsId: {0}", arrValue);
           }
       }
    }

}catch(Exception ex){

}
```

### **Second way: I'm gating wi-fi but couldnt get the SSID**

```
if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()) {
    foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {

   if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 && ni.OperationalStatus== OperationalStatus.Up   ) {
       Network = "NETWORK ( N/A )";
           Wifi = "Wifi (" + ni.Name + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please someone give me clear idea how to get my connected wifi SSID.

Answer (score 5):

```
    // Show SSID and Signal Strength
    private void showConnectedId() {
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan show interfaces";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();

        string s = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string s1 = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("SSID"));
        s1 = s1.Substring(s1.IndexOf(":"));
        s1 = s1.Substring(2, s1.IndexOf("\n")).Trim();

        string s2 = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("Signal"));
        s2 = s2.Substring(s2.IndexOf(":"));
        s2 = s2.Substring(2, s2.IndexOf("\n")).Trim();

        labelStatus.Text = "WIFI connected to " + s1 + "  " + s2;
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Comment: Can I use this in UWP?

Comment: Looks like you cant run netsh from UWP. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below mentioned `WMI` classes. Both are defined in **`cimv2`**

**`SELECT * FROM WiFi_AdapterAssociationInfo`**

**`SELECT * FROM WiFi_AvailableNetwork`**

For more details:[WIFI Information](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/10/15/all-about-wifi-networks-and-wifi-adapters-using-the-wmi-and-delphi/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer and reference WIFI Information

Comment: If that fixes your problem, please considering marking the answer as up vote. If not, please share further issues.

Comment: WMI are not supported in UWP. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/efcf0564-5bdb-44c5-95a8-76395b662b2b/uwp-wmi-support-on-uwp-applications?forum=wpdevelop Just a heads up.

Comment: This is not working at my machine. ([wmisearcher]”SELECT * FROM WiFi_AvailableNetwork”).get() results in:
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Invalid class .

Comment: Same on mine (W10x64): invalid class.

Comment: can you provide information about your environment? hardware and windows info.

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather old library dating back to 2014:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Core version 1.1.0.2
```

Although it is not conforming to .NET Standard, this library integrates with my .NET Core 3.0 app, but obviously is not cross-platform.

Sample code:

```
var networks = NetworkListManager.GetNetworks(NetworkConnectivityLevels.Connected);            
foreach (var network in networks) { 
    sConnected = ((network.IsConnected == true) ? " (connected)" : " (disconnected)");
    Console.WriteLine("Network : " + network.Name + " - Category : " + network.Category.ToString() + sConnected);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do exactly this.
There's a nuget package that appears to wrap the lower level APIs, called [SimpleWifi](https://github.com/DigiExam/simplewifi/blob/master/SimpleWifi/Win32/WlanApi.cs#L131) which worked perfectly for me.

Note that it seems to be a bug-fixing reimplementation of an earlier library: "ManagedWifi", which was throwing unresolvable Exceptions for me, as per here:
[Issues with using Managed WiFi (NativeWiFi API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371871/issues-with-using-managed-wifi-nativewifi-api/60115715#60115715)

Comment: SimpleWifi certainly works but it has not been updated since 2015. I've succesfully used a more recent nuget package called ManagedNativeWifi 
 https://github.com/emoacht/ManagedNativeWifi